Read env variable in a JSON file (chromatic.config.json)
I've started a React 18 project. I did not use CRA or CRACO. I setup deps manually and configured webpack manually.
I have installed storybook 8 and added Chromatic for visual tests.
There is a config file for Chromatic chromatic.config.json with this following
{
  "projectId": "Project:${{CHROMATIC_LOCAL_PROJECT_ID}}",
  "storybookConfigDir": "src/storybook",
  "zip": true
}

My .env file
CHROMATIC_LOCAL_PROJECT_ID=my_secret_token

My package.json
"storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006 -c ./src/storybook",
"build-storybook": "storybook build -c ./src/storybook",
"test-storybook": "test-storybook -c ./src/storybook"

The problem is that I cannot make chromatic.config.json read CHROMATIC_LOCAL_PROJECT_ID variable when running visual tests.
How do I do that? Storing my token in the config file directly does not seem proper (but it works) even though it is generated by Chromatic automatically.
This is what I've got in the terminal

I tried to use .env file but it did not work. I have not found any answer on the internet.
